# Generating/Sending pdf email attachments within a hangfire job

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, razorengine, hangfire, rotativa

In our ASP.NET MVC web application we send emails as part of scheduled tasks handled by Hangfire for which I am using Postal as described [here](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/tutorials/send-email.html)
The method works fine and we are able to send HTML/text emails. Now we need to generate and attach PDF files as well. The attached PDF needs to be generated dynamically by use of a Razor template. First I tried to use Rotativa in order to generate the PDF. However I encountered the problem that method BuildPdf needs a ControllerContext which is not available in the background HangFire process. I tried to fake the ControllerContext as

```
using (var memWriter = new StringWriter(sb))
            {

                var fakeResponse = new HttpResponse(memWriter);

                var fakeRequest = new HttpRequest(null, "http://wwww.oururl.com", null);
                var fakeHttpContext = new HttpContext(fakeRequest, fakeResponse);
                var emailController = new BackgroundEmailController();
                var fakeControllerContext = new ControllerContext(new HttpContextWrapper(fakeHttpContext), new RouteData(), emailController);

                var attachment = emailController.BillAttachment(email);

                var pdf = attachment.BuildPdf(fakeControllerContext);

                if (pdf != null && pdf.Count() > 0)
                {
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(pdf))
                    {
                        var contentType = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
                        email.Attach(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(ms, contentType));
                    }
                }
            }
```

However this raised a NullReference error in Rotativa.
 Then I tried first to compile the template view with RazorEngine to HTML(and then convert the HTML to pdf by some mean)  as

```
var engineService = RazorEngineService.Create();

            engineService.AddTemplate(cache_name, File.ReadAllText(billAttachmentTemplatePath));
            engineService.Compile(cache_name, modelType: typeof(BillEmail));
            var html = engineService.Run(cache_name, null, email);

            using (var ms = CommonHelper.GenerateStreamFromString(html))
            {
                var contentType = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
                email.Attach(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(ms, contentType));
            }
```

And it throws another NullReference in the RazorEngine dynamic DLL:

```
 System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at CompiledRazorTemplates.Dynamic.RazorEngine_bb2b366aaef64f2bbc2997353f88cc9e.Execute()
   at RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateBase.RazorEngine.Templating.ITemplate.Run(ExecuteContext context, TextWriter reader)
```

I was wondering if anybody have suggestions for generating PDF files from a template in a Hangfire process?

Comment: Thanks for editing @rohan-khude

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to commercial solutions, you can try **[Telerik reporting](http://docs.telerik.com/reporting/overview)** and export it as pdf programmatically. You define your report and then invoke it to generate PDF on the server side, finally email the byte[] as email attachment. You can now kickoff this process using Hangfire job.

Here is a pseudo code assuming you have defined the structure of your report, Please look [here for more details on how to create your report programatically](http://docs.telerik.com/reporting/programmatic-control-of-reports).

```
public void GenerateAndEmailReport()
{     
    var reportSource = new InstanceReportSource();
    Telerik.Reporting.Report report = new MyReport();

    //populate data into report

    reportSource.ReportDocument = report;

    var reportProcessor = new ReportProcessor();
    reportSource.ReportDocument = report;
    var info = new Hashtable();
    var result= reportProcessor.RenderReport("PDF", reportSource, info);

    byte[]reportBytes = result.DocumentBytes;

    SendEmail(reportBytes, "myreport.pdf"); // a method that takes the bytes and attach it to email. 
}
```

Additional references from telerik.

- [send report as email](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/send-telerik-report-as-email-attachment)
- [Generating PDF in console application](http://www.telerik.com/forums/generating-pdfs-from-net-console-applications)
- [Saving a report programmatically](http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/reporting/details/saving-a-report-into-pdf-format-programmatically)

Comment: I am not sure about a commercial solution, however I will consider it if there is no other clean way.